# ImportError: No module named easydict

Tags: python, importerror

I'm trying to run the demo of py-faster-rcnn based on [this github page](https://github.com/xinleipan/py-faster-rcnn-with-new-dataset).
I have done all the previous steps. But When I try to run the deo with `python ./tools/demo.py --gpu 0 --net vgg16` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./tools/demo.py", line 17, in
from fast_rcnn.config import cfg
File "/home/hadi/Software/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/config.py", line 23, in
from easydict import EasyDict as edict
ImportError: No module named easydict
```

I have installed easydict with both these commands:

`sudo pip install easydict`

`pip install easydict`

Is this related to python path? I have installed both python 2.7 and 3.5. Since then I get all these python related errors. For example I have installed **tensorflow** for both python 2 and 3. But with python 2 it always says:

> No module named tensorflow

How can I fix this?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Cross-posting the [same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911026/importerror-no-module-named-easydict) on multiple exchanges is considered a no-no on the Stack Exchange.

Comment: That is explained about [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross posted

Comment: @BhargavRao since when exactly is that a close reason?

Comment: @rene cross posts should ideally be closed and deleted but since this has a nice answer, I did not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest trying the following:

First, check if easydict is installed or not On your terminal run:

```
python

from easydict import EasyDict
```

If this doesn't give an error then you have easydict installed. I had installed easydict using Anaconda:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/auto easydict
```

Next, if this is working check if you have pip installed (It should have come installed with Anaconda):

```
which pip
```

This command should give output as `/data/username/anaconda2/bin/pip`

If this is the output then pip was installed with anaconda and not apt-get. In this case you should not use sudo while using pip and while running the code.

So, you should try running the code the following way:

```
bash build/demo.py
```

after that, if still the issue occurs add this following line to your `demo.py` file

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/')
```

Comment: when I run `python` and import easydict it says **No module named easydict**. But with `python3` it works fine. I think when I use `pip` command it installs in python3. The same goes with `pip3`. When I run `which pip` the result is : **usr/local/bin/pip**. How can I set `pip` to install modules in python 2.7 instead of python 3?

Comment: Using `pip2 install easydict` solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try the following command in terminal :

 
 `sudo pip2 install easydict`

This worked for me well .